# how to animate an element using js

Tags: javascript, css

i made a navbar for practice and tried to hide and show its content only when its title is clicked.
i managed to do it with toggling a `hidden class` on and off.
but i also want it to have transition and slide down not just to apear out of nowhere. i couldn't do this part.

i put `transition` inside `nav-bar__list-box` tweaked the `hidden` class with and without `display:block` but i didn't have any success.

hidden class:

```
.u-hidden-navbar {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0 !important;
}
```

idk what else to do but to ask here for advise.

```js
const btnNavBar = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-bar__heading-box");
const navList = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-bar__list-box");

for (let i = 0; i < btnNavBar.length; i++) {
  btnNavBar[i].addEventListener(`click`, function () {
    navList[i].classList.toggle("u-hidden-navbar");
    for (let b = 0; b < navList.length; b++) {
      if (b !== i) {
        navList[b].classList.add("u-hidden-navbar");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.u-hidden-navbar {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0 !important;
}

.nav-bar {
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 30rem;
}
.nav-bar__heading-box {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.nav-bar__heading-box:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1b1b1b;
}
.nav-bar__list-box {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  transition: 5s all ease;
}
.nav-bar__item:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1b1b1b;
}
.nav-bar__link {
  padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem;
  color: #973ae4;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.4s all ease;
}
.nav-bar__link:hover {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.nav-bar__link:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  box-shadow: inset 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.5rem rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.6);
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-bar__link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #973ae4;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<aside class="nav-bar">
        <div class="nav-bar__heading-box">
          <h3 class="heading-tertiary">HTML Topics</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar__list-box u-hidden-navbar">
          <ul class="nav-bar__list">
            <li class="nav-bar__item">
              <a
                href="pages/js_topic_01.html"
                class="nav-bar__link"
                target="content"
                >Link</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__item">
              <a
                href="pages/js_topic_01.html"
                class="nav-bar__link"
                target="content"
                >Link</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar__heading-box">
          <h3 class="heading-tertiary">CSS Topics</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar__list-box u-hidden-navbar">
          <ul class="nav-bar__list">
            <li class="nav-bar__item">
              <a
                href="pages/js_topic_01.html"
                class="nav-bar__link"
                target="content"
                >Link</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__item">
              <a
                href="pages/js_topic_01.html"
                class="nav-bar__link"
                target="content"
                >Link</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar__heading-box">
          <h3 class="heading-tertiary">JS Topics</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar__list-box u-hidden-navbar">
          <ul class="nav-bar__list">
            <li class="nav-bar__item">
              <a
                href="pages/js_topic_01.html"
                class="nav-bar__link"
                target="content"
                >1- JS High-level overview</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__item">
              <a href="hello.html" class="nav-bar__link" target="content"
                >Link</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser does not know how to interpolate this kind of animation, so you'll have to be a little bit more specific about how you'd like the hidden element to appear.

Switching from `display: block` to `display: none` or from `visibility: visible` to `visibility: hidden` is a "on/off" situation with no way to guess what the middle state will be...

Instead you could try to transition from :

- `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`
- `transform: scaleY(0)` to `transform: scaleY(1)`
- both

You can be really creative, and rely on keyframed animations with several intermediate steps, but it's up to you to define the strategy.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.togglable').classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
.togglable{
  padding: 50px;
  background: red;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: .75s;
}

.togglable.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<div class="togglable hidden">Hello</div>
```

Comment: thank you. i understand now about the middle state of properties, however in my example i need to have the list container to go from zero height to the default height. and whats important for is that containers when they expand they should push other elements away. i cant think of any other way to do this without changing the height or display.

Comment: Then you can simply switch from `height: fit-content` to `height: 0`, without introducing `display` or `visibility` changes in your hidden class. Also make sure to check out the [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) CSS property so the animation runs as smoothly as possible

Comment: yeah thats what i did at first and it works but i cant animate the height change . thanks alot for your time brother, i think i should learn more js and css animation before trying this kinde of things.